# How to export dynamoDB table's entire records to CSV from aws console?

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, export-to-csv

I am new to AWS, just working around dynamo DB for first time..

I have a table in dynamoDB with close to 100,000 records in it. 
I want to export these records to CSV file.

I have tried all possible options in aws console, found that we can only export 100 records at a time, which will not scale well to 100k records,

I did some search around it, exporting to S3 is doable for larger record set.

But I cannot opt that way because of S3 & data pipeline expenses.

Please suggest any work-around (if any).

Answer (score 5):

This application will export the content of a DynamoDB table into CSV (comma-separated values) output. All you need to do is update config.json with your AWS credentials and region.

[AWS DynamoDBtoCSV](https://github.com/edasque/DynamoDBtoCSV)